# Accented characters using jquery

Tags: jquery, diacritics

I have this script included in the body of my html file:

```
<script>
function read() {
    $.get("prevision.txt", function(data) {
        $('#prev').html(data);
    });
}

$(document).ready(read); </script>
```

When there is an accent included in the .txt file, the #prev shows: � instead of an accent.

I have all files encoded as UTF-8.
How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Is prevision.txt served as UTF-8 (HTTP headers) ? What's the server ?

Comment: Yes, my txt is served as UTF-8. My server is Nominalia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the html codes instead of true characters.

for Ex.

```
'<' == '&lt;' // true
```

complete reference for accented chars [here](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/web/codehtml.html)

Comment: I would prefer to write accents normally :/